# How to UV Unwrap without Split Edges (Geometry Nodes) ? Can I create something like Smart UV Projection?

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I don't understand UV in Geometry Nodes very well. I have watched a lot of tutorials, most of them use *Split Edges* method. Is there a way for me to unwrap UVs from the model without using *Split Edges* ? I really want to do Smart UV Projection Right in Geometry Node.

[image]